# Limit strtok to 3 tokens only

Tags: c, tokenize

I have data string which looks like : `3,1,6,IN,88`.
I need to get only the first 3 cycles ( 3 | 1 | 6 | **IN,88** )
So it will stop the loop before the last `,` and last string will be `IN,88` :

```
char *pch=strtok (data,",");
 while (pch != NULL)
        {
            //works well here
            pch = strtok (NULL, ",");
        }
```

which will also split the `IN,88` , and I want to keep it with the comma inside .

Just setting a counter to break at 3 will obviously not work.
Is there a simple way to achieve this without changing data ?

Comment: Try using a `for` loop instead?

Comment: I must be efficient here. its hardware. So you mean using strtok with for loop ?

Comment: Try using a different delimitor set for the last token, so as not to break at the comma.

Comment: I can't change data structure. The whole system is based on that.

Comment: No, I mean the delimitor set you pass to `strtok`.

Comment: Thanks, can you show example? not sure I get you.

Comment: For the final token use `pch = strtok (NULL, "");` instead of `pch = strtok (NULL, ",");` then it won't break at the comma in `IN,88`

Comment: Great idea ! not sure why I missed that.. Thanks,

Comment: A `for` loop will give you very little overhead. But if you're worried about even that (don't be until you *measured!*) then how about just three calls to `strtok` in a row? Don't overcomplicate things! :)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thats also a good option. I am going to check that on the hardware to see who performs better. Thanks.

Comment: @WeatherVane works great, i think its faster then making a for loop, not sure about memory.

Comment: pch = strtok (NULL, ",");  for what is this ? why not char *pch=strtok (strtok (strtok (data,","),","),",");

Answer (score 0):

You need the untokenized part of the original string after tokenization. You also need to tokenize the input string a specified number of times. You can try this for that.

```
char *tmp; // will store the untokenized part of the string
int count; // how many times the string will be tokenized
tmp = data; // before starting to tokenize, the whole input is untokenized
char *pch = strtok (data,",");
count = 1;
while (pch != NULL && count <= 3) // you want to tokenize thrice
{
    tmp = tmp + strlen(pch) + 1; // shift the pointer pointing untokenized string
    pch = strtok(NULL,",");
    count++;
}
tmp = tmp + strlen(pch) + 1; // shift the pointer after last tokenization
```

After this, if you do `puts(tmp);`, you will get the untokenized part of the string as output.